# Remove Windows Developer License from computer

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8

I need to remove my Windows Developer License from a particular computer.
So I used this powershell command

```
Unregister-WindowsDeveloperLicense -Force
```

This seems to work because it doesn't show any error message. But when I execute this command to check if the license has been removed

```
Get-WindowsDeveloperLicense
```

The same message that has been showing up from the begining shows up again :

```
 ExpirationTime                      IsValid
 --------------                      -------
 31/12/9999 23:59:59                 True
```

So how can I completely unregister a developer license ?

**EDIT :**

I don't know if this changes anything, but i'm trying this on a surface.

Thanks.

Comment: You need Administrator permissions to remove a developer license. Are you running as admin?

Comment: Yes I am. Besides, like I said no error message has showed up.

Comment: Does it survive a reboot?

Comment: Yes already tried it :)